# How to implement gradient reversal layer in TF 2.0?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

This layer is static, it is a pseudo function. In the forward propagation it doesn't do anything (identity function). In the back propagation however, it multiplies the gradient by -1. There are lots of implementations on github but they don't work with TF 2.0.

Here's one for reference.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.framework import ops

class FlipGradientBuilder(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.num_calls = 0

    def __call__(self, x, l=1.0):
        grad_name = "FlipGradient%d" % self.num_calls
        @ops.RegisterGradient(grad_name)
        def _flip_gradients(op, grad):
            return [tf.negative(grad) * l]

        g = tf.get_default_graph()
        with g.gradient_override_map({"Identity": grad_name}):
            y = tf.identity(x)

        self.num_calls += 1
        return y

flip_gradient = FlipGradientBuilder()
```

Comment: Docs are here: https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/guide/eager#custom_gradients

Comment: @PedroMarques Thanks for the link. But docs are still not obvious. For example, they define a function clip_gradient_by_norm but they don't explain where to use it.

Comment: For instance, if you are using Keras to build your graph, you would invoke this function from a Lambda layer. By default Tensorflow tracks the tensor operations inside the graph definition and uses its auto differentiation rules to compute the gradient. custom gradients tell it to use the user defined grad function instead of the gradients computed by auto differentiation (for the scope of this function).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Dummy op that reverses the gradients

This can be done using the decorator `tf.custom_gradient`, as described [in this example](https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/guide/eager#custom_gradients):

```python
@tf.custom_gradient
def grad_reverse(x):
    y = tf.identity(x)
    def custom_grad(dy):
        return -dy
    return y, custom_grad
```

Then, you can just use it as if it is a normal TensorFlow op, for example:

```python
z = encoder(x)
r = grad_reverse(z)
y = decoder(r)
```

### Keras API?

A great convenience of TF 2.0 is it's native support for Keras API. You can define a custom `GradReverse` op and enjoy the convenience of Keras:

```python
class GradReverse(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def call(self, x):
        return grad_reverse(x)
```

Then, you can use this layer as any other layers of Keras, for example:

```python
model = Sequential()
conv = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(...)(inp)
cust = CustomLayer()(conv)
flat = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(cust)
fc = tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_classes)(flat)

model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=[inp], outputs=[fc])
model.compile(loss=..., optimizer=...)
model.fit(...)
```

Comment: Stackoverflow community needs a lot more people like you. Thanks.

Comment: One more thing, I'm not an expert but I think you should have wrapped the function as a lambda layer rather than a stateful layer, cause it is static. Am I right?

Comment: @FalconUA, the solution with Keras API is elegant, but I cannot make it work. I tried the bare-bone code (cf., https://www.dropbox.com/s/cld1ntar1zb3z89/file.py?dl=0) and get error **ValueError: Attempt to convert a value (<tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f57f060e198>) with an unsupported type (<class 'tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D'>) to a Tensor.**

Comment: @Jatala It looks like you are passing the previous layer itself as the argument, rather than calling it and passing the result. I haven't looked at your code, but often this is due to misplaced parens.